# How can I generate a private key for an account set up by yum?

Tags: linux, yum, service, accounts

I am using EC2 and am new to the world of Linux, and I've looked for an answer to this but I think I'm just not sure how to ask the question correctly.

I have installed Jenkins and git using yum, under the account *ec2-user*, and they install fine.  Yum created an account called *jenkins* which runs the Jenkins process (checked this using `ps -aux` and the user is jenkins).

I have a remote git repository that uses public/private keys.  When I `ssh-keygen`, and then connect to my remote git repository through ec2-user, everything is fine.  I'm just not certain how or where to create a key for the jenkins user.

This is where my trouble starts.  When I `su jenkins` and then `cd ~`, I wind up in `~ec2-user`.  When I run `ssh-keygen` as jenkins, it wants to put the key into `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa`  - and that doesn't seem right.

How can I create a key pair for jenkins, or should I just have it added to the `~ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `su jenkins`, use `su - jenkins`.  Then you should inherit the environment of the jenkins user, and key creation etc. should proceed painlessly.

Comment: The prompt still shows me as ec2-user.  Is that correct?

Comment: Jenkins user will not have a shell set up by default (by design), which is why it's dropping immediately back to ec2-user. add -s /bin/bash to the su command to specify a shell.

Comment: That is an excellent point; would you mind if I edited it into my answer?  Or if you would prefer to do the edit, please do, and I'll approve it (though this is somewhat less reliable as I need a second user to approve it).